# Merge info not getting recorded in mergeinfo property

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn

I have merge code from a branch to trunk using SVN merge tool (not the `svn merge` command but using UI). I use `TortoiseSVN`.

When I run following command `svn propget svn:mergeinfo <<URL_to_trunk>>` then I cannot see the merge information getting recorded in `mergeinfo` property.
Even if I use this command with branch URL then as well I cannot see the recorded merge info.

I read following line in [SNV book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo).

> The svn:mergeinfo property is automatically maintained by Subversion
>   whenever you run svn merge.

- Does this mean that `mergeinfo` property would be updated only when merge is done using `svn merge` command from command line and not merge using UI?
- If not then why I cannot see merge info using `svn propget svn:mergeinfo <<URL_to_trunk>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the previous answer, tortoise will also not record merge info if the "ignore ancestry" is checked

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The svn:mergeinfo property should be correctly added to merged files even when using Tortoisesvn.
You should run the "svn propget" command on merged files in your working copy, to see the svn:mergeinfo property.

Comment: Did you run the command on a file that has been **modified** by the merge, in your working copy ?

Comment: In the 'svn propget' command, please specify the path of a file that has been modified. The trunk folder does not have the mergeinfo property, only the modified files have it.

Comment: "*The trunk folder does not have the mergeinfo property, only the modified files have it*" .. Not true, subversion has concept of tracking merge information through `svn:mergeinfo` property .. Check this -  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo

Comment: I wanted to say: "trunk folder __may__ not have the mergeinfo property." However modified files must have it. Use --recursive option.

Comment: Trunk folder also have it, mergeinfo property is at root level .. Infact most of the svn properties are at root level, and this is to keep track or provide information on whats going on with the svn created ..